# Script to test staging server statuses

Tags: shell-script, monitoring

I am just trying to write a script to test the staging server statuses for my organization. What I am looking is to add a loop in the script, that checks all the server status and alerts us by an email or a message something like that when a server broken down or low!

This is how we want the script to look like, I am not sure how to write it.

```
#!/bin/bash
array[server1, server2..]
 loop()
   if (condition to check all the servers)
   then
     echo "server is in good status"
   else
     echo "server is down" -->if its down an email to 
                                    Example@example.com
   fi
```

This is what I tried, any suggestion and help please will be great!

```
#!/bin/bash

    ping -c $1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
          echo "server is alive"
    else
         echo "this was't was good server"
    fi
```

Comment: Or for maximum overkill pick something from https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#monitoring

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to test a specific service rather than to use an ICMP ping request.  Presuming you accept this advice, here is an example that will test the secure shell daemon:

```
hostlist=(host1.example.com host2.example.com)
for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
    if nc -w 2 -z $host 22; then
        echo "INFO: ssh on $host responding"
    else
        echo "ERROR: ssh on $host not responding"
    fi
done
```

Comment: But if  I want to make it more like it  captures the type of error it is returning (500,503,402, etc) and add that in the message, How do i do it?

Comment: That's a different question, but you can use a similar script that checks the output of e. g. `curl --silent -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.com/`.